# How use two fragment in Android DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I try to use Android NavigationDrawe - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
I have one activity and two fragments.
My main problem is layout in android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout. 
One fragment use -content_frame and other - content_footer. This element would be in bottom (height - wrap_content). I have tried different variations, but did not work. All examples is with one fragment. What I am doing wrong? thank you
My main layout file. With this show one fragment.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >    
 </FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    >    
 </FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" /> 
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When change to:

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
        >    
     </RelativeLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >    
     </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

shows both fragments, but on one another. [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26351044/Screenshot_2013-07-22-21-17-30.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to have a fragment at the top, and you want the second fragment as a footer on the screen. It's unclear if you want scrolling or not, so I'll just assume not. The DrawerLayout doesn't actually do much in terms of laying out elements to my knowledge, so I'd recommend putting a layout inside the DrawerLayout to position your fragments as you want. Do something similar to the untested code I'll put below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="80" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Best of luck! Hope that helps!

Comment: when i LinearLayout change to:  
'android:layout_width="fill_parent"'
android:layout_height="fill_parent"'
and @+id/content_frame change:
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="1"
work and show both fragmens. Work. But understand, why not working with RelativeLayout.

Comment: @egidijusb I just made an edit. Now it should give 20% of the screen to the footer, and 80% of the screen to the first fragment. Try that. My hope wasn't to give you a 100% working example, but rather to show you that you can use a layout inside the DrawerLayout and thus position things as you would like. I can't do much if you don't know how to use a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout.

Comment: @egidijusb Just saw your other comment. It should work with a Relative Layout just fine. You must be using it incorrectly. You have to set the first fragment to alignParentTop="true" and alignParentLeft="true", and also set it above the footer fragment, and you have to set the second to alignParentBottom="true" and alignParentLeft="true". From there it should just simple layout fiddling.

Comment: Work it. Thanks. If i will scroll content_frame, i must this place to ScrollView. Yes?

Comment: @egidijusb Yeah, if you want to be able to scroll the top part put the content_frame inside of a ScrollLayout.